# OkHttp3 - SocektTimeoutException when using specific local address

Tags: java, sockets, networking, okhttp

I have problem with using `OkHttp3` client with overriten `SocketFactory`. I' ve implemented my custom `SocketFactory` in the same way it is implemented [here](https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/e484fa1548b7e34b95972826f40dce0b5fe32f35/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/oksocial/network/InterfaceSocketFactory.kt)

Some of the requests works, but most of the times when I try to execute http request I get error:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
> at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
> at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:120)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
> at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

Does anyone knows where the problem is?

I've check that my local interface has connection to network, some of the request works fine so I guess problem is not here. I expect every single http request to work without errors.

Comment: First question, why are you overriding the network? What network is it using, and does that network have access to the target address? Do the same addresses fail?

Comment: Is this Android or JVM?

Comment: It is JVM. I have several network interfaces on the serwer (ens5, ens6, ens7), I want to use specific network interface, or use for example one interface by one http client and other interface by other http client.
Running command `curl --interface ens5 http://www.google.com` works for every interface, also some of the requests from OkHttp client are passing too.
When I run netstat command I can see many connections in SYN_SENT state.

Comment: I'd suggest trying it with a socket and if you can reproduce, then raise a bug as a possible JVM bug.  Also try reproducing this separately, with OkHttp and try it against other VMs, JDK 17 if you are using 8 or 11?